# Visual Studio 2022 Template Intellisense for Parameter Packs?

Tags: c++, c++20

So Microsoft added a new feature for intellisense called ["Template Intellisense"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/template-intellisense/). The feature is really useful but I came across a problem, I can't seem to understand how I will use it for parameter packs. I've look through their documentation several times but I can't seem to find anything for parameter packs. A help would be nice! :)

```
template<typename fmt, typename... args>
void call(fmt _fmt, args&&... args)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: From [template-intellisense-gives-error-with-variadic-template](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/template-intellisense-gives-error-with-variadic-te/484182): *"The Template Bar of the "Template IntelliSense" feature does not currently support variadic templates."* (Mar 25, 2019).